# Do I clear Customs during a transit in the USA en route to Toronto?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, ewr

I am flying from the Middle East to Toronto.

I have a United Airlines flight from Frankfurt to EWR terminal B, and my connection to Toronto is from Terminal C.

Do I need to clear customs or immigration in the USA, or just personal security check & hand baggage check when I move from terminal B to terminal C?

Answer (score 17):

Contrary to most other countries, there is **no** sterile international transit in the US.

**All passengers** arriving in the US, whether it's their final destination or they transfer to a domestic or international flight, will have to:

- go through **passport control** (and thus have a valid US passport, green card, visa, or ESTA),
- **reclaim luggage**
- go through **customs**.

After customs, if you are on a single ticket and checked through to your final destination, you will be able to drop off your bags (already tagged for your final destination) at a counter just after exiting customs. You can then go to departures, through security, and to your gate (possibly changing terminals in the meantime).

If you are on separate tickets, you will have to go the the check-in area for your flight to check-in and drop your luggage before you can go through security and to your gate.

There are two exceptions:

- If you arrive from a "**pre-clearance airport**", where checks will have been done at the departure airport, you will be considered as arriving on a domestic flight. But this does not apply for Frankfurt at this time.
- If you transit in MIA or DFW **and** you arrive from selected airports on selected airlines and you got red luggage tags, you will still go through passport control and customs, but you will not need to reclaim/recheck luggage. There's a pilot in ATL for flights from ICN (!) to do the same thing. But none of those apply to you.

Note that in all cases, since you will be entering the US, you need to meet all requirements for entry into the US, not only from an immigration point of view (as described above, US passport, green card, visa or ESTA), but also for Covid-related measures (vaccination and recent test).

Comment: I did several time without reclaiming luggage. Some airlines on some airports may be able to do it. In any case one must pass custom (and TRANSIT) in the custom form. But yes, it is complex, you should complete also ESTA (and pay for it), and queues are usually long (it is not the custom or baggage reclaim which take time). I would recommend not to use such route. Especially considering you are already changing in Europe. Try to see if you can change the flights (COVID added some extra option to change flights)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi The only exception I know how where you don't need to reclaim you luggage is if you arrive from a pre-clearance airport (checks will have been done at the departure airport instead of when arriving in the US). Otherwise I don't think it's possible (unless you don't have hold luggage of course!). You need to reclaim your bags before going through customs.

Comment: The pre-clearance exception will apply to the return trip. You will clear U.S. customs in Toronto for the flight to Newark.

Comment: "sterile international transit " Do you mean "sterile" as in "useless" or as in "isolated"? If it means useless then I beg to disagree, I find international transit making a far more enjoyable experience, starting with less time lost. The first time I had to transit through a US airport I discovered that 2 hours might not even be enough to clear everything which is a pity.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek “Sterile transit” is a common term for international transit connections that do not require clearing customs and immigration.

Comment: @jcaron: no (and why?). Moving baggages is just a technical implementation. As I wrote, I did pass to immigration and to custom control (and I should declare the goods I had). Just that I must not physically move my baggage. Some years ago I linked in one comment in this site about a statement of Delta about this in Atlanta. In any case, I did it several times (Europe to South America). It is not the question if it is feasible, I did it.

Comment: @ GiacomoCatenazzi the point of customs is that they should be able to inspect all your luggage, that’s why in the US you have to reclaim your bags before going through customs with them (and then drop them off again just after customs), even if you are leaving the US again immediately (partly because you could end up staying in the US after all). I’m not aware of any exceptions since international-to-international transit ended 18 years ago, and I can’t seem to find any. If you find the statement on this topic that would be very interesting, maybe Delta managed to convince CBP at some point…

Comment: @PatrickMevzek In what context does "sterile" mean "useless"?

Comment: @T.J.L. see fifth form at https://www.dictionary.com/browse/sterile : "not productive of results, ideas, etc.; fruitless." Don't we say "sterile conversation" for example? (at least we do that in French, but English is not my mother tongue)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi There is apparently an ITI program in MIA and DFW which allows some passengers to not reclaim and recheck their luggage (but still go through passport control and customs), though the conditions are unclear (origin airport? Airline? Something else?). There's apparently a pilot in ATL for flights from ICN, though it's unclear if that's for ITI or ITD. But those are really exceptions. Don't know if ATL had more exceptions in the past.

Comment: @StephenC.Steel Hi Steve! Porter flies to Newark from Billy Bishop (YTZ) and does not have customs pre-clearance. I have no idea what the proportion of passengers flying from YTZ vs YYZ is, but there are some.

Comment: @jcaron, In Toronto (YYZ terminal 1 at least) you can transit from international to a precleared US (or domestic Canada) flight without rechecking luggage due to a smart baggage handling system. The latter hangs onto the luggage until you clear immigration, giving customs the option of having the bags delivered to them if they want to look at them, or just let them go. For passengers originating in Toronto this also lets them put US immigration after the security checkpoint rather than ahead of it. I assume US airports could use similar systems to allow transit without a bag reclaim(?).